# Memory leak in TensorFlow program

Tags: python, memory-leaks, tensorflow

My program suffers leaking memory and I cannot quite figure out why. Here are some memory stats obtained by `mem_top` after it has accumulated 3 GB of unnecessary memory:

```
refs:
28226   <class 'dict'> {1: <tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Operation object at 0x7fa4cc149550>, 2: <tensorflow.python.fram
14113   <class 'dict'> {'Const_4136': <tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Operation object at 0x7fa3ad179550>, 'rnn/map_1/whil
5575    <class 'list'> ['# module pyparsing.py\n', '#\n', '# Copyright (c) 2003-2015  Paul T. McGuire\n', '#\n', '# Permiss
4095    <class 'list'> ['# Copyright 2015 The TensorFlow Authors. All Rights Reserved.\n', '#\n', '# Licensed under the Apa
3592    <class 'set'> {<tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Operation object at 0x7fa448620048>, <tensorflow.python.framework.
2770    <class 'list'> ['# Copyright 2015 The TensorFlow Authors. All Rights Reserved.\n', '#\n', '# Licensed under the Apa
2468    <class 'list'> ['# Copyright 2015 The TensorFlow Authors. All Rights Reserved.\n', '#\n', '# Licensed under the Apa
2010    <class 'list'> ['# Copyright 2015 The TensorFlow Authors. All Rights Reserved.\n', '#\n', '# Licensed under the Apa
1912    <class 'list'> ['# Copyright 2016 The TensorFlow Authors. All Rights Reserved.\n', '#\n', '# Licensed under the Apa
1882    <class 'dict'> {9914368: <weakref at 0x7fa585dc4548; to 'type' at 0x974800 (managedbuffer)>, 140348670317568: <weak

types:
246109   <class 'dict'>
207253   <class 'tuple'>
149516   <class 'list'>
69645    <class 'weakproxy'>
69050    <class 'google.protobuf.internal.python_message._Listener'>
32579    <class 'function'>
31374    <class 'tensorflow.core.framework.attr_value_pb2.AttrValue'>
25638    <class 'google.protobuf.internal.containers.RepeatedScalarFieldContainer'>
14230    <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>
14183    <class 'google.protobuf.internal.message_listener.NullMessageListener'>
```

The only special things I am doing that I can think of is that I have ternary operators inside the fetches for `tf.Session.run` like this:

```
run([my_op if not my_flag else tf.constant(0.0), ..], ..)
```

But it could be completely unrelated to this. It seems that there are about 6 more `dict` instances added per training step.

Any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: Are u modifying your graph between run calls? Can use .finalize to make sure u dont

Comment: Ah, it seems the `tf.constant`s modify the graph! I guess a better way of dealing with optional fetches would be to do branching and use different `run` calls?